# JavaScript Array Race Condition/Threading issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var globalArray = [];
```

This callback gets fired up to 100 times per second

```
function EventCallback(param) {

globalArray.push(param);

}
```

Main part of the program where I process the list of items.

What happens if the callback gets fired while in the middle of modifying the array here?

```
while(globalArray.length > 0) 
{

ProcessListItem(globalArray.shift());

}
```

The issue I'm running into is that Firefox Spidermonkey javascript engine is sometimes bugging out (race condition/threading issue?) and telling me that globalArray.push is not a function or other strange errors.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the callback add items to a list so I can process them later. Is there any better way to code this? I'm new to this so any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your callback can't fire while in your `while` loop because JavaScript is single threaded.

Answer (score 5):

It will not happen, since JavaScript runs single threaded in your browser. The event will only be fired if the browser has nothing else to do.